# How do I index an object in python?

Tags: object

I have a dictionary of objects,

e.g.
{'a': (one, two, three), 'b': (four, five, six)},

and i want to know how to pull out specific parts of each object in the dictionary so that i end up with a list of things that are in a certain position in each object.

For example ending up with; [two, five] (second position in each object)

How do you index the object so that this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this directly with an index operation, but the usual Pythonic approach is to use a list comprehension; e.g.

```
>>> D = {'a': ('one', 'two', 'three'), 'b': ('four', 'five', 'six')}
>>> [val[1] for val in D.values()]
['two', 'five']
```

Keep in mind that dictionaries are inherently unordered, so the order of the result is ambiguous in this case.

If you want a dictionary of the results, you can use a dictionary comprehension, e.g.

```
>>> {key:val[1] for key, val in D.items()}
{'a': 'two', 'b': 'five'}
```

For more information, you might check out the [Python List Comprehension Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).